# Do we have integrability in these cases?, a version of Doob-Meyer decomposition.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

There are as I can see several version of the Doob-Meyer decompositions, I am looking at this version where we do not talk about class D or uniform integrability.

> Let Z be a cádlág submartingale. Then Z has a decomposition  $Z =
> Z_0+M-A$ where M is a local martingale, and A is an increasing process
>   which is predictable, and $M_0=A_0=0$

As I have understood, in this general case, we can not say anything about the integrability of A and M?

But look at this specific case please. Let $X$ be a square integrable martingale. Then it follows that X has a cádlág-modification, and we use that. Look at $Y=X^2$, by Jensen, this will be a cádlág-submartingale, since also we assumed that X was square integrable.

If we use the theorem above we have that:

$X^2(t)=X^2(0)-A(t)+M(t)$.

What we do know is that $\int_\Omega X^2(t)(\omega)dP<\infty$.

But can we in this case tell if M and A also are integrable with respect to P for a fixed t? If one is integrable it would follow easy from the triangle ineqality, but I am not sure how if so I would show this?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[N.B. You have a sign error: $Z=Z_0+M+A$, with $M$ and $A$ as described.]

Because $A$ is increasing and $A_0=0$,
$$ 
X_t^2\ge M_t,
$$
and so $\Bbb E[M_t^+]<\infty$. Let $\{T_n\}$ localize $M$. Then, for each $n$, $M_{t\wedge T_n}$ is a martingale with initial value $0$,  so 
$$
\Bbb E[M^-_{t\wedge T_n}]=\Bbb E[M^+_{t\wedge T_n}]-\Bbb E[M_{t\wedge T_n}]=
\Bbb E[M^+_{t\wedge T_n}]-\Bbb E[M_{0\wedge T_n}]=\Bbb E[M^+_{t\wedge T_n}]\le\Bbb E[X_{t\wedge T_n}^2]\le\Bbb E[X_t^2].
$$
By Fatou,
$$
\Bbb E[M^-_{t}]=\Bbb E[\liminf_n M^-_{t\wedge T_n}]\le\liminf_n\Bbb E[ M^-_{t\wedge T_n}]\le\Bbb E[X^2_t]<\infty.
$$
Thus $M_t$ is in integrable. Finally, $\Bbb E[A_t]=\Bbb E[X_t^2-X_0^2]-\Bbb E[M_t]$ is finite as well.

Comment: Thank you that was very smart. Based on your idea I tried something similar to simplify it a bit, but then I had to use that the negative part of a martingale is a martingale, and that is maybe not correct?

Comment: The negative part function is convex, so the negative part of a martingale is a *sub*martingale.

Comment: I apologize, but could you please explain the last ineequality in the fifth line?($E[X_{t\wedge T_n}^2]\le\Bbb E[X_t^2]$), how do you get this?

Comment: $X^2$ is a submartingale, and $T_n\wedge t$ is a stopping time bounded above by $t$.